# How to find out the latest version of Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, version

I have opened an Android Studio project which was created some time ago and the IDE says that a gradle plugin for Kotlin supports a Kotlin version 1.2.51 or higher. I would like to set it to the latest version but I have to go to the Kotlin website on which it's not easy to find out this information.

Is it possible to find out the latest version of Kotlin in Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio->Tools->Kotlin->Configure Kotlin Plugin Udpates

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are on windows do the following:

FILE > SETTINGS > LANGUAGE AND FRAMEWORK > KOTLIN UPDATES

[image]
then click on check and then if there was a newer version press install

Comment: On macOS I had to go to Android Studio -> Preferences instead of File -> Settings

Answer (score 15):

On Mac OS

Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin