# Android Studio Upgrade to not-latest version of kotlin plugin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'd like to upgrade the kotlin plugin bundled with Android Studio to a newer version (1.4.30), but not the latest version (1.4.31). The reason is that I think there's a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66449550/installing-kotlin-plugin-1-4-31-causes-android-studio-to-not-highlight-syntax-er) with the latest one, but I would still like to use a version of the plugin that's relatively new instead of the one that comes bundled by default with the latest version of Android Studio (1.3.72 - almost a year old).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So is your question asking how to set the Kotlin plugin version?

Comment: No, it's how to install it in Android Studio. I set it in build.gradle but get the warning about the mismatch with the one bundled with Android Studio. I'd like to know how to install a newer plugin version in Android studio so that it matches the one in my build.gradle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the latest version of Kotlin in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682098/how-to-find-out-the-latest-version-of-kotlin-in-android-studio)

Comment: No, the answer shows how to install the latest version of Kotlin in Android Studio. My goal is to update to a newer version, but not to the latest version.